# Is it possible to programatically remove a single past revision from master?

Tags: git, revision-history

Let's say I have a file with a number of revisions;

```
initial commit text
revision one
revision two
revision three
revision four
```

at some later date, I want to remove some change that happened a number of revisions ago, but keep later changes, for example remove only the changes made in the second revision;

```
initial commit text
revision one
revision three
revision four
```

Currently, I am calling up the diff for the second revision, and doing a search and replace on the master by hand, but I was wondering if there was some functionality that would allow me to simply take out that previous revision, and I guess apply all the ones that come later?

EDIT:  None of these are quite working out based upon something I didn't make clear.  The "code" up there represents the actual text of a file being reverted, so when I suggest removing the second revision, I mean the literal text that says "revision two".

I have tried both the rebase and revert tools, and they balk because adding the following two lines "revision three" and "revision four"... well I keep getting merge conflicts where the file ends up reading;

```
initial commit text
revision one
<<<<<<< HEAD
revision two
revision three
revision four
=======
>>>>>>> parent of 4ac4327... revision 2
```

meanwhile the text of the error (this one is for revert, though rebase is similar)

```
error: could not revert 4ac4327... revision 2
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

I'm having no problem using revert or rebase so long as it is a single step back, removing the text "revision four", but any attempt further just seems to fail on me.

I try to do an add and commit, and when I --continue, I get

```
error: no cherry-pick or revert in progress
```

and I file with the extra three git messages in the file.

EDIT TWO:  I think the process I am looking for is to check out at the first revision, and then use git cherry-pick...  I'll update as soon as I figure it all out here...

Comment: `git rebase -i` also called interactive rebase (you could read about it). Then when prompted through the editor, just remove the line, save and quit. Done!

Answer (score 5):

`git revert` adds a *new* commit that undoes whatever the given commit did. For example, given

```
a initial commit text
b revision one
c revision two
d revision three
e revision four
```

(with some really truncated hypothetical hashes on the left), you could run

```
git revert c
```

to produce something like

```
a initial commit text
b revision one
c revision two
d revision three
e revision four
f revision five
```

where `f` is equivalent to what you are doing now: undoing what you find in the diff for `c`.

This comes with less risk than rebasing, and is safe for branches that you have already shared.

Comment: I was a bit unclear up there, I was using the text "revision xxx" as an example of literal text in the file, so removing "revision two" would literally remove that line.

I tried the revert, but when I attempted it, it simply put new text in my file before the revision I tried to remove and after the later revisions (see above) and then threw an error at me.  I tried resolving the error, but it turns out the error was just a complaint that I had not commited this.

Comment: `git` can't undo arbitrary changes to a file, only the commit in which the change was made. If, for example, the same commit added `revision two` and `revision four`, `git` alone cannot undo only *part* of that commit; you would have to first *split* the commit into two commits (the one with the changes you want to undo, and the one with the changes you want to keep). They, you could revert the to-undo commit, or delete it. This is a much more involved rebasing process, and still rewrites history.

Comment: The help for `git rebase` contains a section "SPLITTING COMMITS" that walks you through the process of replacing a commit with 2 or more new commits.

Comment: The result unfortunately, is the same as my edit up there.  So far, rebase, revert, and cherry-pick have all sdded the text of revision two along with three and four, but also adding 'HEAD' and '=========' to the text of the file.

Comment: That's a merge conflict. There's no general answer to the question you are asking, because the answer depends on the history that led to the current state.

Comment: And, each revision is separate.  Still writing extra content into my file, I wonder if the diff is just screwy or something.

Comment: That's just it, I'm showing the literal history.

the words 'revision one' is the literal first revision. 'revision two' is the literal second, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [interactive](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) [rebase](https://billtheconqueror.com/2018/07/24/commit-early-commit-often-the-interactive-rebase-delete/) to delete the commit.

The steps for an `interactive rebase`,

1. `git rebase -i <revision before the one to delete>`
2. In the text editor, delete the desired commit
3. Save and exit editor

Note: The commits after the one deleted will be rewritten.  If the branch has already been pushed, doing a rebase will force you to have to force push the branch. This should be a coordinated effort with your team, unless you are sure that you are the only developer using the branch.

Answer (score 1):

At the time I'm writing this, there are two previous answers.  Each mentions a way to do what you're asking; but some context is missing that's important if you're deciding which one to use.

The intended way to undo the changes from one commit in git is to `git revert <commit>` that commit.  As chepner explains, this will create a new commit that reverses the "patch" from the targeted commit.  The `<commit>` argument can be a commit ID (the hash value unique to the target commit), or an expression that points to the commit (such as `HEAD~2` - meaning "go back 2 from the currently checked-out commit" - in your example).

Note that if a change in commits 3 or 4 overlaps with a change from 2, the revert can create conflicts, which must be resolved much like a merge conflict.  Also, sometimes an interaction between `git revert` and a merge commit can cause issues - but that is only likely to matter if what you're reverting is a merge, or maybe if it is a commit whose changes are already present in a later merge.  If you search on "revert merge" or something similar, you should find existing answers that detail those issues (should they arise).

The reason people sometimes balk at that solution is, they don't want their history to show what they now perceive as their mistakes.  I will say that objectively that shouldn't be the priority, but there are alternatives that remove the target commit from history... for a cost.

Those alternatives, collectively, are called history rewrites.  If the history is shared, they can put the repo in a state that causes problems for other users until the perform a clean-up, and if they perform the clean-up incorrectly then it will undo the change and put commit 2 right back in.  So you have to make sure all repo users are on board with what you're doing.

Additionally, a history rewrite almost always runs the risk of creating broken commits.  This is because you are rewriting commits 3 and 4 in an automated way, creating states of the code that have never been tested.  Since 4 is the new "tip of the branch", probably you'll test it; but if you don't also go back and test 3, it could be a break in history, which might interfere with future troubleshooting (e.g. with `git bisect`).

Commands like `git rebase -i` or `git filter-branch` can be used to rewrite history, but you should make sure to understand the above issues before deciding to use them in this way.  I recommend reading the section "recovering from upstream rebase" in the `git rebase` documentation; it applies to history rewrites in general.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue Resolved**

The problem I was facing was a question of tools, and my lack of understanding was upon diff and merge.

The only familiarity I had with diff was reading commit messages on github / gitlab, which are pretty straightforward.  From the command line, this was a new experience for me, and most tutorials I found were either simple test cases that would not throw up errors (remove last revision) or made the assumption that the user understood the changes needed in more complex cases like I was describing.

When git (rebase, revert, or cherry-pick) takes action and throws out an error, it (as may be obvious to many, but not myself) writes those errors into the file itself.  The strange messages I was running into was the fix itself, I merely did not have the contextual knowledge.  It did not help that the tool I was using for diff / merge was attempting to fix those errors in the simplest way possible, namely returning the very commit that I was attempting to remove.  I still have no idea how to get that tool to remove those parts, and I have stopped trying.  I threw together a quick macro for vim and all is fine now.

So, the issue was not with git, but with diff.  Perform the git action appropriate, when git throws out an error, resolve the issue in the file itself, understanding that the changes are marked between HEAD and  =======, with the trailing commit following that and it's sha hash.  Continue the git operation, and it should not throw out any more errors.